# Why is the question about Slytherin speaking Parseltongue closed?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

This question, [How does Salazar Slytherin speak Parseltongue? [duplicate]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157362/how-does-salazar-slytherin-speak-parseltongue).

In the comments Valorum, who closed the question, states:

[image]

So, Valorum states that no one predates Salazar Slytherin, but: the answer to the linked question, which mind you I linked states that "Herpo the Foul" predates Salazar Slytherin. 
[image]

But "Herpo The Foul" obviously predates Salazar Slytherin which is the reason for the close.

So how is this a duplicate. Since I researched this and even linked the question being stated as the duplicate?

Comment: @Valorum, if that question is not canon, then my question is even more relevant.

Comment: @Valorum - Sounds like you're thinking of Paracelsus (who has dubious dating and was occasionally listed as discovering Parseltongue). Herpo (who comes from high canon sources) actually predates Salazar and was never said to have discovered Parseltongue.

Comment: @ibid - I think you're right. Oh well. It's been hammered open again and now has a pretty worthless answer that basically replicates what's in the other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/54283/31394) asks **whether Slytherin was the first Parselmouth**, to which the answer is **no, because Herpo the Foul predated him**.

The [new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/157362/31394) asks **how Slytherin came to be a Parselmouth**, which is not covered by either the question of whether he was the first or the answer that he wasn't.

Not a duplicate. I've reopened your question. Thanks for bringing it up here.

Comment: Thank you,can you delete the comments too please?

Comment: @KyloRen Valorum might delete his own comment once he realises he was mistaken, but in the meantime I've left his comment there with a clear refutation, just in case anyone else makes the same mistake.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The issue here is that the answer to the duplicate does mention a Parselmouth that predates Salazar Slytherin. Where it leaves some wiggle room for a fresh question is that it doesn't make it *explicitly* clear that he's the **only Parseltongue mentioned in any level of canon that predated Salazar.**

Instead of mod-hammering this question back open, it would have been far more sensible to simply add that fact as a microscopic (three or four word) edit to the duplicate which already talks about Herpo.

---

For the record, linking to another question doesn't stop it from being a duplicate :-)

Comment: No , but it shows the research has been done and the question has not been answered.

Comment: -1. The fact that Herpo is the only known Parselmouth to predate Slytherin doesn't necessarily answer the question of how Slytherin came to be a Parselmouth.

Comment: @KyloRen - yes, but it's not a panacea against it being a duplicate.

Comment: @RandAl'Thor - Hmm. That sounds like a distinction without a difference.

Comment: @Valorum -- I don't think the question used to close the question as a dupe addresses the same issue. If I'm reading correctly, the question is *How does Salazar Slytherin speak Parseltongue?* The answers of who else spoke Parseltongue, or who spoke it first, don't seem to fit with the original question. Am I missing something? :)